# Loading and playing with soundpool from assets

Tags: android, soundpool

I have a bunch of sounds, assigned to a group of buttons, which i need to play. All my sounds are in asset folder. However, it does not work. **The purpose is:** *to load from assetFodler and play that sounds*. I will come out with code examples from my project:

```
//set up  audio player
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

 //getting files lists from asset folder
    aMan = this.getAssets();
    try {
        filelist = aMan.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For the purpose of do not having a lot of code lines, I created a basic procedure for *loading* and *playing* sounds:

```
public void loadSound (String strSound, int stream) {

    try {
        stream= mSoundPool.load(aMan.openFd(strSound), 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     mSoundPool.play(stream, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, LOOP_1_TIME, 1f);
}
```

As you can see I pass file(stringName) and streamID.

Finally, here is how i use it:

```
     case R.id.button1:
        //if button was clicked two or more times, when play is still on im doing stop
    mSoundPool.stop(mStream1);
    loadSound(filelist[0],mStream1);
        break;
```

When I run project, nothing happens and logcat says:

```
12-09 10:38:34.851: W/SoundPool(17331):   sample 2 not READY
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPD1:
When I do it this way, without having loadSound procedure it works fine
the following code is onCreate:

```
//load fx
    try {
        mSoundPoolMap.put(RAW_1_1, mSoundPool.load(aMan.openFd(filelist[0]), 1));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and Onclick button:

```
  //resourcePlayer.stop();
        mSoundPool.stop(mStream1);
        mStream1= mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(RAW_1_1), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, LOOP_1_TIME, 1f);
```

I just dont want to have so much code lines, i wanted to make it look nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to check file is loaded successfully before playing it using [SoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener.html)

Change your `loadSound` method code as:

```
public void loadSound (String strSound, int stream) {
     boolean loaded = false;
     mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
    try {
          stream= mSoundPool.load(aMan.openFd(strSound), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   // Is the sound loaded already?
   if (loaded) {
     mSoundPool.play(stream, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, LOOP_1_TIME, 1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: well, nothing happens. seems it is not loading... why?

Comment: @Daler : because everything executing in a sequence in your current code so make some wait after `mSoundPool.load(aMan.openFd(strSound), 1); `called .you can also see http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/27/android-soundpool-how-to-check-if-sound-file-is-loaded/ example

Comment: unfortunately, i must not have any delays when user will click on button. It has to play immediately. Any ideas of how to achieve it? Actually I can make it to play immediately by using R.raw, but i want to do it from assets..

Comment: then try after moving `mSoundPool.load(aMan.openFd(strSound), 1); ` inside activity onCreate method and `if (loaded) {
     mSoundPool.play(stream, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, LOOP_1_TIME, 1f);
    }` lines inside onResume of Activity

Comment: @Daler : or u can also implement a Thread for playing music when mSoundPool.load is ready.

Comment: i have about 20+ sound which has to be played, and they are all in one activity, so dont see a point to have another thread. Having them load from asset folder would make my job much easer, when i will create a list of that sounds... thanks )

Comment: I suggest you also check what's in your filelist variable

Comment: @TanjaV, and ρяσѕρєя K i have updated my code.. any ideas now?